# How to integrate swagger with restify framework in node?

Tags: node.js, rest, swagger, swagger-ui, restify

Could you help me how to implement API with swagger?I have found many applications which are using with express.
I'd really appreciate if someone can point me in the right direction.

Comment: swagger-node packge for node seem to be well documented and it can get you started very easily. did you try something the SO can help fix? :)

Comment: @AndreiTerecoasa yes I have tried but not getting proper solution. Thanks!

Comment: I'm confused. Is it possible to integrate swagger with restify. Most of the documentation is implemented with express.